# Remove duplicates from a list of list based on a subset of each list

Tags: python, performance, list, python-3.x

I wrote a function to remove "duplicates" from a list of list.

The elements of my list are:

```
[ip, email, phone number].
```

I would like to remove the sublists that got the same EMAIL and PHONE NUMBER, I don't really care about the IP address.

The solution that I currently use is :

```
def remove_duplicate_email_phone(data):
    for i in range(len(data)):
        for j in reversed(range(i+1,len(data))):
            if data[i][1] == data[j][1] and data[i][2] == data[j][2] :
                data.pop(j)
    return data
```

I would like to optimize this. It took more than 30 minutes to get the result.

Comment: Using `pop` on a list should really *never* be done for arbitrary positions, in a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach could be to use a `Counter`

```
from collections import Counter

data = [(1, "a@b.com", 1234), (1, "a@b.com", 1234), (2, "a@b.com", 1234)]
counts = Counter([i[:2] for i in data])

print [i for i in data if counts[i[:2]] == 1]  # Get unique
```

Answer (score 4):

Your approach does a full scan for each and every element in the list, making it take O(N**2) (quadratic) time. The `list.pop(index)` is also expensive as everything following `index` is moved up, making your solution approach O(N**3) cubic time.

Use a set and add `(email, phonenumber)` tuples to it to check if you already have seen that pair; testing containment against a set takes O(1) constant time, so you can clean out dupes in O(N) total time:

```
def remove_duplicate_email_phone(data):
    seen = set()
    cleaned = []
    for ip, email, phone in data:
        if (email, phone) in seen:
            continue
        cleaned.append([ip, email, phone])
        seen.add((email, phone))
    return cleaned
```

This produces a *new* list, the old list is left untouched.

Comment: Just a style question - any reason you use `continue` instead of just handling the not-seen case?

Comment: @erip: I like avoiding too many levels of indentation. You can indeed invert the test and indent the remaining two lines of the loop too.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution might be to use groupby.

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

deduped = []

data.sort(key=itemgetter(1,2))
for k, v in groupby(data, key=itemgetter(1,2):
    deduped.append(list(v)[0])
```

or using a list comprehension:

```
deduped = [next(v) for k, v in groupby(data, key=itemgetter(1,2))]
```

Comment: `groupby` requires that the input is sorted. If it is *not* already sorted on the grouping criteria, then you have to add that at a O(NlogN) cost, this is *non-trivial* with a large list when there is a O(N) linear time solution available instead.

Comment: That's true, but unless the list needs to be sorted several times every day and it has millions of entries, I don't think the performance penalty from sorting before grouping is a big deal, or even noticeable.

Comment: Compared to a solution that doesn't need sorting *at all*, of course it'll be noticeable. It's an important caveat; unless you need the data to be sorted for other reasons and keeping it sorted is not going to be a burden, it definitely needs to be mentioned as a drawback.